# hardware implementation of algorithms using in os scheduler

Tags: operating-system, cfs

1.in os when a new process comes ,  does hardware make interrupts (while another process is running) for os to create  a new PCB data structure for this new process ?

2.Consider Completely Fair Scheduling (CFS) algorithms  : when a process is running (there is one cpu core) as we know it gives priority to  a process that has lowest run time until current time , consider a process that is running and the quantum does not expire yet  , in this time one process s state turns to ready , Will this make interrupt (so os  can  reschedule) ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.in os when a new process comes , does hardware make interrupts (while another process is running) for os to create a new PCB data structure for this new process ?

No; typically the hardware has no idea what any OS uses to keep track of processes (e.g. the contents and order of a PCB data structure's fields, if the OS has a PCB data structure at all, how the OS manages/keeps track of various structures, etc).

Instead, existing software typically calls a kernel system call that provides information about the new process, and the kernel constructs whatever data structures that the kernel wants.

For one possible example; an OS might have a "`int SpawnProcess(char *executableFileName, char *processName, int maxThreadPriority)`" function; and (when someone calls that function) the kernel might construct a PCB (and set the process name field in that structure to whatever the caller said, set the file name field, set the max thread priority, etc), then set other fields (CPU time consumed by process, number of threads belonging to process, amount of memory consumed by the process, ...) to default values; then put some kind of reference to the new PCB on some kind of a master list of processes that exist; then create a TCB (thread control block) for the process' initial thread (and set fields in that structure to default values - thread state, initial thread name, initial thread priority, signal mask, default CPU register state, etc); then put some kind of reference to the new thread in the new process' PCB; then put some kind of reference to the new thread on a scheduler queue (so that the scheduler knows the thread exists and will give it CPU time). When the scheduler actually does give the new process' initial thread some CPU time, it might start running kernel code that creates a new virtual address space, then loads the executable file and does things like dynamic linking of shared libraries (before finding the entry point from the executable file and jumping/returning to the executable's entry point). All of that is done with normal software without any special hardware features.

> 2.Consider Completely Fair Scheduling (CFS) algorithms : when a process is running (there is one cpu core) as we know it gives priority to a process that has lowest run time until current time , consider a process that is running and the quantum does not expire yet , in this time one process s state turns to ready , Will this make interrupt (so os can reschedule) ? thanks.

This works in the opposite order. Something will happen (a kernel system call or an IRQ) that will (eventually, after device driver and/or other kernel code does some work) cause one or more blocked tasks to unblock and become ready to run; and when that happens (e.g. when an "`unblockTask(taskID task)`" function in the scheduler is called by something else in the kernel) the scheduler may decide if the recently unblocked task should/shouldn't preempt the currently running task (and scheduler itself may have no clue why the task was unblocked or if any system call or interrupt was originally involved).

Comment: thansk a lot  . i think i should ask my first question in this way : does this (first question) cause an immediately interrupt at cpu(consider a process that is currently running inside cpu)  ?